# How to extract the value from the <td> element within the table using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

I'm trying to extract the value **`1`** from the table with Selenium, but I'm not finding a good way to do it.

```
<td width="1%" style="text-align: right">1</td>
```

Here is how the page's HTML looks like:

```html
<tr class="linhaPar" onMouseOver="javascript:this.style.backgroundColor='#C4D2EB'" onMouseOut="javascript:this.style.backgroundColor=''">
   <td>
      Scientific American
   </td>
   <td>
      A Base Molecular da Vida  Uma Introducao a Biologia Molecular
   </td>
   <td>
   </td>
   <td>
      <table width="100%">
         <tbody style="background-color: transparent;">
            <tr>
               <td>
                  1971
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </td>
   <td width="1%" style="text-align: right">
      1
   </td>
   <td width="1%"> 
      <a id="formBuscaPublica:ClinkView" href="#" onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.getElementById('formBuscaPublica'),{'formBuscaPublica:ClinkView':'formBuscaPublica:ClinkView','idTitulo':'39117','idsBibliotecasAcervoPublicoFormatados':'47_46','apenasSituacaoVisivelUsuarioFinal':'true'},'');}return false"><img id="formBuscaPublica:ImageView" src="/sigaa/img/view.gif" style="border:none" title="Visualizar Informa&ccedil;&otilde;es dos Materiais Informacionais" /></a>
   </td>
```

I've tried using this code, but it didn't work at all.

```
x = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="listagem"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/').text
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following xpath:

```
x = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tr[@class="linhaPar" and contains(.,"Scientific American")]//td[contains(@style, "text-align")]').text
print(x)
```

**Note**:

Don't use `.find_elements`, but `.find_element`

Comment: What if the "Scientific American" string is variable? I mean, this is a library project that I'm trying to make, so if I search for other book titles, then I would get different results. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @davi_m correct, you can use "Scientific American" as variable, you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it, I created a re-usable function that returns the first element by tag and matching attributes.

```
def getElementByTagAndAttributes(browser, tag, **kwargs):
    for element in browser.find_elements_by_tag_name(tag):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            attribute = element.get_attribute(key)
            if attribute != value:
                break
        else:
            return element

x = getElementByTagAndAttributes(browser, "td", width="1%", style="text-align: right").text
```

Answer (score 0):

As its a table structure and data represent in rows and column. You can go with finding the value based on some specific data. So in your case lets say you want to retrieve the value `1` based on "Scientific American" then go with below xpath -

```
x = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr/td[contains(.,'Scientific American')]/following-sibling::td[4]").text
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text **1** from the element:

```
<td width="1%" style="text-align: right">1</td>
```

You can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based solutions:

- Using the text *Scientific American*:

  ```
  print(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[contains(., 'Scientific American')]//following::td[3]//following-sibling::td[1]").text)
  ```
- Using the text *A Base Molecular da Vida  Uma Introducao a Biologia Molecular*:

  ```
  print(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[contains(., 'A Base Molecular da Vida  Uma Introducao a Biologia Molecular')]//following::td[2]//following-sibling::td[1]").text)
  ```